How to virtualize a responsive Bootstrap grid?
A Bootstrap grid can wrap its columns into rows when the viewport width is smaller than a configured breakpoint. This changes the row height and interferes with Razor virtualization which wants to know the height of the virtualized elements. How can I make virtualization play nicely with a responsive grid?
I thought about using Bootstrap display classes to display one virtualized grid for widths above the breakpoint and an entirely different one for widths below it. I haven't tried this yet because I'm too new to Bootstrap and Razor to be confident in any solution even if it appeared to work.

Using Bootstrap display classes to display different virtualized grids depending on display size "works" in the sense that Virtualize doesn't spam errors in the console. But this exhibits a problem that may have no general solution. When the content switches between 3 columns and 1 column, the browser maintains its absolute scroll position rather than its relative scroll position. So if you're looking at item 300 in 3-column mode and you narrow the viewport, you'll be looking at item 100.
I may just live with this for now. My main goal is to support mobile and desktop browsers, and I don't expect desktop users to resize their browser that often.
@page "/virtualize"

<!-- 3 columns at or above md -->
<div class="container d-none d-md-block">
    <Virtualize Items="Rows" Context="row" ItemSize="100">
        <div class="row" style="height: 100px">
            @foreach(var i in row)
            {
                <div class="col-4">
                    <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; border: solid;">
                        @i
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
    </Virtualize>
</div>

<!-- 1 column below md -->
<div class="container d-block d-md-none">
    <Virtualize Items="Items" Context="i" ItemSize="100">
        <div class="row" style="height: 100px">
            <div class="col-12">
                <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; border: solid;">
                    @i
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </Virtualize>
</div>

@code {
    private List<int> Items => Enumerable.Range(1, 1000).ToList();
    private List<int[]> Rows => Items.Chunk(3).ToList();
}

